# Why this unexpected behavior in pushing letters [a-z] in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, letter

new in PHP.
I want an array of letters from 'a' to 'z', I tried to loop it with a `for` loop but I got an unexpected behavior.

```php
$array_letters = [];

for($i = 'a';$i <'z'; $i++){ //this is from 'a' to  'y' because it's < 'z'
    $array_letters[] = $i;
}

print_r ($array_letters);
```

> When I try this way I get:
> `Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e [5] => f [6] => g [7] => h [8] => i [9] => j [10] => k [11] => l [12] => m [13] => n [14] => o [15] => p [16] => q [17] => r [18] => s [19] => t [20] => u [21] => v [22] => w [23] => x [24] => y )`
> as expected

but when I try

```php
$array_letters = [];

for($i = 'a';$i <='z'; $i++){ //This is supposed to be from 'a' to 'z' because of the <='z'
    $array_letters[] = $i;
}

print_r ($array_letters);
```

I get this unexpected behavior.

> Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e [5] => f [6] => g [7] => h [8] => i [9] => j [10] => k [11] => l [12] => m [13] => n [14] => o [15] => p [16] => q [17] => r [18] => s [19] => t [20] => u [21] => v [22] => w [23] => x [24] => y [25] => z [26] => aa [27] => ab [28] => ac [29] => ad [30] => ae [31] => af [32] => ag [33] => ah [34] => ai [35] => aj [36] => ak [37] => al [38] => am [39] => an [40] => ao [41] => ap [42] => aq [43] => ar [44] => as [45] => at [46] => au [47] => av [48] => aw [49] => ax [50] => ay [51] => az [52] => ba [53] => bb [54] => bc ... [673] => yx [674] => yy [675] => yz )

What is wrong?

Comment: Because `aa` is `<= 'z'` lexicographically and so on and so forth. This is expected behaviour too.

Comment: This has been asked before.  Why not use `range()`?

Comment: I see, it's seems to be different in Java (where I come from) because 'a' and 'z' are treated as codepoints due they are `char` literals,  It would be just treated lexicographically if the were String literals, double quoted this way: "a" and "z".

But it's not possible doing that in a for loop, that's why It was unexpected to me.